# Javascript program help

Tags: javascript

Update this program is supposed to keep track of the number of times each side is rolled not each roll itself.

I am working on a javascript exercise that needs to take two dice, roll them 1000 times and keep track of each roll. I thought the best way to do it was to use an array but I am not exactly sure if I am going in the right direction with what I am doing. I just need a little help in pointing me in the right direction to get this to work because right now it doesnt output anything. Thanks here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Exercise Five</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function Die(){
        this.roll = function(){
            this.sides = 0;
            return parseInt((Math.random( ) * 1000) % this.sides) + 1;  
        }
    }
</script>

</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dieOne = new Die();
    var dieTwo = new Die();
    var rollOne = 0;
    var rollTwo = 0;
    var roll_value = new Array();
    var arrayPlace = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < 1000 ; i++){
        rollOne = dieOne.roll();
        dieOne.sides = 10;
        rollTwo = dieTwo.roll();
        dieTwo.sides = 10;
        arrayPlace = (rollOne + rollTwo) - 2;
        roll_value[arrayPlace]++;
    }

    for( var i = 0; i < roll_value.length; i++){
        document.writeln(roll_value[i]);
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: `dieOne.sides = 10;` You probably want to do that *before* you roll the die, not after. And no need to reset this inside of the loop every time.

Comment: Sorry it doesnt output anything and i have checked it with the webdeveloper tools on firefox and it acts like everything is fine

Comment: `var sides = 0; return parseInt((Math.random( ) * 1000) % sides) + 1; ` Looks like it would divide by zero every time.

Comment: @thilo I have fixed that. That is a good point

Comment: @Thilo that actually works fine, it was the first part I tested without multiple dice rolls and the if statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, see updated code below:

```
var dieOne = new Die();
var dieTwo = new Die();
var rollOne = 0;
var rollTwo = 0;
var roll_values = new Array();

for(var i = 0; i < 1000 ; i++){
  rollOne = dieOne.roll();
  rollTwo = dieTwo.roll();
  roll_values[i] = { 'first': rollOne,
                     'second': rollTwo,
                     'value': 0 };
  // 1. iterate through past roll_values[i].first, roll_values[i].second
  // in order to determine what you need to increment and by how much

  // 2. finally set roll_values[i].value = var_containing_value;
}

for( var i = 0; i < roll_value.length; i++){
  console.log(roll_value[i]);
}
```

And, another note, for debugging, `console.log(whatever)` is excellent and supported on most modern browsers (IE > 8, thanks Kolink). The console log will show up in the javascript/error console.

There were two problems: how you were storing the roll values and how you were incrementing your array. Both should now be fixed.

Comment: I have tested it again just to make sure but my random generation function works fine

Comment: I did have to change var sides back to this.sides, but it does work. That part was actually given to me in the book

Comment: Sorry I didnt specify enough, this program needs to keep track of each time the value is rolled. so if it rolls 2 5's then the roll amount is 10 and it needs to remember that 10 was rolled once. then when it rolls 10 again it needs to increment to 2 and so on and so fourth

Comment: I've provided some hints which should help you. By using hash objects for your roll_values array, you can keep track of multiple values with ease, which should allow you all the history you need to determine appropriate values for the rolls.

Comment: `console.log()` is supported in IE8+

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  function Dice(sides) {
    this.sides = sides;
  }

  Dice.prototype.roll = function() {
    return (Math.random() * (this.sides + 1)) | 0 ;
  }

  var counts = [];
  var d1 = new Dice(6);
  var d2 = new Dice(6);
  var s;

  for (var i=1000; i; i--) {
    s = d1.roll() + d2.roll();
    counts[s] = typeof counts[s] == 'undefined'? 1 : ++counts[s];
  }

  // Show results
  for (var i=0, iLen=counts.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    console.log(i + ' : ' + counts[i]);
  }
```